# Is there a working example showing how turn-based games work in iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, game-center, ios5

Is there a sample project like the one demo'ed in WWDC showing how turn-based games work?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not at the moment. And it is a pity as setting up a working game center turn based game is quite the effort (took me over a week to do it for the first time).